# Excluding certain destinations from navigation backstack?

Tags: android, android-navigation

Is there some way I can prevent certain destinations in my navgraph from being added to the backstack?

For example, lets say I have 5 fragment destinations: `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and `E`.
navgraph looks like this: `A` -> `B` -> `C` -> `D` -> `E` -> `A` (its a loop)
Now `B`, `C`, `D` and `E` are fragments that I dont want the user to be able to navigate back to. If the user navigates back at any point in the navgraph, I want them to go to the previous `A` fragment.

I'm currently doing this by overriding `onBackPressed` with complicated logic that keeps popping the back stack until a fragment `A` is reached.. It works but it feels far from optimal. If I could simply prevent `B`, `C`, `D` and `E` fragments from being added to the backstack it would be much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION 1**:

The `app:popUpTo` and `app:popUpToInclusive` are exactly what you may be looking for

Via the documentation,the xml attributes will

*Pop up to a given destination before navigating. This pops all non-matching destinations from the back stack until this destination is found*

Let me explain this to you with three fragments `A` , `B`, `C`

```
A (start) -> B -> C
```

if I want to navigate to `C`
and pop all **including** `A`(startscreen) then the code will be:

```
 <action
            android:id="@+id/B_to_C"
            app:destination="@id/C"

            app:popUpTo="@+id/A"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
```

if I want to navigate to `C` and pop all excluding `A` then the code will be:

```
  <action
            android:id="@+id/action_B_to_C"
            app:destination="@id/C"

            app:popUpTo="@+id/A"/>
```

**SOLUTION 2**:

Using the `popBackStack` method of the `NavController` class which does the same job as the `onBackPressed` but in an elegant way

If you have three fragments : `A`, `B`, `C`

And you are currently in fragment `C` and would like to go back to `A` before navigating anywhere(or not navigating anywhere if you please)

```
NavController controller = Navigation.findNavController(view);
controller.popBackStack(R.id.fragmentB, true);
```

OR

```
NavController controller = Navigation.findNavController(view);
controller.popBackStack(R.id.fragmentA, false);
```

where `true` or `false` will indicate if you actually want the destination to stay(`false`) or be popped off the stack too (`true`)